# Apache Solr is blocking API after adding security.json . How to unblock API calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, solr

I have created security.json file to add basic authentication and authorization for my application which is developed in node js in backend and react js in front end.
I am using solr 8.8.0.

Here is security.json code

```
{
    "authentication":{
    "blockUnknown": true,
    "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="
    }
},
    "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
    "role":"admin"}],
    "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
    }
}
```

Main purpose here to enable authentication in when hit following URL
http://localhost:8983/solr first user name and password should be asked.
[image]
Above script does ask for user name and password but it is blocking API calls which are using solr.

Comment: "solr-spec: 5.5.0" does not seem like Solr 8? If you don't want to block the Solr API; why add a security.json? Are there specific parts of the API you want to allow while blocking other parts?

Comment: You probably want `"permissions":[{"name": "all", "role": "admin"}]` as a first step. Then for regular users, you would define specific role(s) and the corresponding permission(s), fine-tuned for such role(s).

Comment: @matsLidh I added security.json to have authentication to solr admin